# Sigma-algebra generated by collection of cylinders.

Tags: measure-theory, semiring

Let $X$ = {$0,1$}$^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all infinite sequences of $0$’s and
$1$’s. A typical element $x \in X$ is written as $x = x_1x_2x_3$···. A cylinder set is
a subset of $X$ of the form
{$x \in X; x_1 = a_1,x_2 = a_2,...,x_m = a_m$},
with $a_i \in$ {$0,1$} and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. The collection $S$ of
cylinder sets is a semi-ring and is closed under finite intersections. We have
also shown that the set function $\mu : S →[0,1]$ given by
$\mu(${$x \in X; x_1 = a_1,x_2 = a_2,...,x_m = a_m$}$) = (1/2)^m$,
can be uniquely extended to a measure on $\sigma(S)$, and we denote this measure
also by $\mu$.
Let $B$ be the set
$B := ${$x \in X; x_2 = 0,x_4 = 0,x_6 = 0,...$}.

Show that $B \in σ(S)$.

My attempt is:

$S$ can be written as $S =  \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}S_m$, where $S_m =$ {$x \in X; x_1 = a_1,x_2 = a_2,...,x_m = a_m$}. Then if $x_2 = 0$ in $S$, $B \in S$.

Since $\sigma(S)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S$, and $S$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra, it follows that $\sigma(S) = S$ and hence $B \in \sigma(S)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I’m not sure about your definition of $S$.  You have a set of cylinders $S_m$, where $S_m$ is of length $m$.  There is, however, more than one cylinder of each length (for $m>0$), but your union only has one such cylinder.  Also $S$ is defined as a set of sets, but the union does not result in a set of sets.

Comment: So in this case it would be $S =$ {$Sj$} for $j \ in \mathbb{ N}$ .  And since $S$ is a collection of all cylinders, it must contain an element equal to $B$ ?

Comment: How can you claim that $B$ is a cylinder set when you have defined a cylinder set as one whose first $m$ elements are fixed, but $B$ has only every second element fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct. $B$ is an intersection of cylinder sets, not a union. $B=\bigcap_N \{x: x_2=0,x_4=0,\cdots, x_{2N}=0\} \in \sigma (S)$. Note that $\{x: x_2=0,x_4=0,\cdots, x_{2N}=0\}$ is the union of the cylinder sets $\{x:x_1=a_1, x_2=0,x_3=a_3,x_4=0,\cdots, x_{2N-1}=a_{2N-1},x_{2N}=0\}$ over all possible values of $a_1,a_3,...a_{2N-1}$.

Comment: Actually your sets $\left\{x:x_{2}=0,\ldots,x_{2N}=0\right\}$ are not cylinder sets either. But they are finite unions of cylinder sets so in the generated $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ali True. I have made it more explicit now.  Actually,  the standard definition of cylinder set does not require conditions on all of the coordinates up to some point. Conditions on any finite number of coordinates are good enough . But OP's definition is different.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_N = \{x = x_1x_2 \dots x_{2N} \in \{0,1\}^{2N} \mid x_2=x_4= \dots = x_{2N} = 0\}$ and for $x \in X_N$, let $S_x$ be the cylinder

$$S_x = \{y=y_1y_2 \dots \in X \mid y_1= x_1, y_2=x_2, \dots , y_{2N} = x_{2N}\}.$$ Notice that $X_N$ is finite for every $N \in \mathbb N$.

Then you have

$$B = \bigcap_{N \in \mathbb N}\bigcup_{x \in X_N} S_x$$ proving that indeed, $B$ belongs to $\sigma(S)$.

*What you wrote in the question is not correct, as you lack the way to formalize the fact that $S_x$, in general, is a finite union of cylinders.*